# Проблемы с JOOMLA на сервере LAMP в LINUX ЧПУ

Tags: linux, joomla, веб-сервер, lamp

Я новичок, учусь системному администрированию. Вообщем поставил сервер LAMP в linux установил CMS JOOMLA 3. Так вот админка полностью работает а вот сам сайт нет, например ссылку такого вида не открывает joomla/map выдает Not Found Подскажите новичку где я ошибся и как это исправить?

Ах да вот еще, когда в настройках отключаю ЧПУ то все работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не знаю, что именно Вы делали, но, скорее всего Вы пропустили эти шаги:
- Проверяем, что есть `mod_rewrite` для Апача;
- Переименовываем `htaccess.txt`, что идет в комплекте с CMS, в .htaccess;
- Включаем ЧПУ в админке.
Если после этого не работает, то показываем содержимое `.htaccess`, и разбираемся дальше.

Comment: Уже разобрался, проблема была в файле .htaccess его как бы вообще не было, я его скопировал с дистрибутива наново и все пошло.